# Why is `Object() === new Object()` equal to `false`?

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

Why it returns false?

```
let a = new Object()
let b = Object()
console.log(a) // {}
console.log(b) // {}
console.log(a===b) // false
```

I checked a proto of a and b too and it is the same.

So what is the difference?j

Comment: `I checked a proto of a and b too and it is the same.` but the instances are not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instance of objects are not the same even:

```
let a = new Object();
let b = new Object();
console.log(a===b) // false
```